# asp.net 2nd combobox not taking selectedvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm loading a record to an aspx page.  I have two comboxes. (AJAX comboboxes in this case)  The second Loads based on the id from the first.

When I pass a key to the page in the query string I retrieve data into a class, then I populate the page fields from the class. When I set the carrier.selectedvalue = class.1value the selection shows correctly. When I set product.selectedvalue = class.2value the selection does not take.  (The product has nothing selected)

If I drop down the list of the product combobox the correct data is loaded based on the the first combox (carrier).

I have tried two methods:

1)  query product sql dataset (2nd dataset) based on selected value from the carrier combox
2)  Load ALL products (2nd dataset) then FILTER the products based on the value from the carrier combox

Both methods load the 2nd combox with the values I need.  Neither method helps me get the product combobox to show the selected value once the page renders.

Note that I'm doing all this in page_load

-Thanks in advance for looking.

Comment: At what point are you trying to set the selected value of the second combobox? If this is all being done in Page_Load the databind might interfere with setting the selected value. Could also be viewstate.

Comment: Gthompson83 I'm guessing that you are correct.  I'm setting the 2nd value in page_Load after the first combobox is set.   Just trying to figure out where to move the set on the second combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gthompson83 put me on the right track.  It was a databinding issue.  I moved the set of the product combobx (the second combobox) to the databound event like so:

```
    protected void cboProduct_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the Product cbo 
        cboProduct.SelectedValue = c.Product_ID.ToString();
    }
```

That is all it took.  The class is still populated in the Page_Load event based on values from the query string.  Once the DataBound event is fired i use the values I've placed in the class to set the value of the product combobox.

Some helpful info is here:  [Databinding events for data-bound controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls)

On the page linked above there is a good section on "Nested Data-Bound Controls".

Note that I did not follow that example completely... I did not do the databind on the second combobox programmatically... just catching the DataBound event was enough to allow me to set the selectedvalue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing everything in Page_Load. Do things in the following order in the following events to prevent your issue:

1. Page_Init: Populate Carrier Items
2. Page_Init: Set Carrier selected value
3. Page_Load: Clear Items `Product.Items.Clear()`
4. Page_Load: Populate Product Items
5. Page_Load: Set Product Selected Items

See this guide for how to effectively use the Page events: http://attemptsatprogramming.blogspot.com/2011/03/practical-guide-to-aspnet-event-model.html

Comment: I'm not sure that is going to work.  On the page you listed it says this:  "One caveat to remember about Page_Init is that it cannot be used to initialize controls or populate lists when the initialization value is dependent on the value of another control".  It is... the 2nd combox depends on the value of the first.  From what I read about Page_Init you can't be guaranteed that page controls are created yet...